# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: could not import module 'myproject.wsgi': No module named wsgi

Tags: python, django, virtualenvwrapper

I'm using Virtualenv wrapper and having issues to runserver.

The full error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application 'myproject.wsgi.application'      could not be loaded; could not import module 'myproject.wsgi': No module named wsgi
```

I have the file wsgi.py at settings.py`s directory.

Anyone can help me?

I was looking to my application's behavion and my local_settings.py is not being imported to, can be some misconfiguration?

Thanks!

Comment: haven't you called your app `django` or maybe the name is the same as your project's name?

Comment: no, my project's name is myproject.

Comment: What version of Django are you running? did you upgrade it recently?

Comment: I'm using Django 1.5...the only thing that I made was installing virtualenvwrapper...but this is looking fine. I can see all things in my pip freeze > requirements.txt.

Comment: what is your project structure, settings.py config and pythonpath and other relevant envs values?

Comment: do you have an (most likely empty) __init__.py in your project folder?

Comment: Do you have an app or another package/module that's called 'myproject', besides the top-level package?

Comment: Sorry guys about the delay, my problem was misconfiguration. Virtualenv was not fully ok. Thanks for all replies.

Comment: @RafaelGomes what was the problem? I'm having it too!

Comment: @RobertGrant I forgot to create the wsgi.py file.

Comment: Ah, thanks :) Mine was totally different; I'd included some South-bsaed code in an __init__.py and had upgraded to 1.7 and removed South. Doh.

Comment: Wow...this is a trick error. :(